# Button + Spinner onItemSelectedListener doesn't work

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button, android-spinner

I'm having trouble using buttons and programmatically spinners, because onItemSelectedListener doesn't work as it has to do properly. I've been googling and searching in this forum, and even there are some problems related to mine, I can't solve it, because I don't have the Spinner declared in my layout.

Here is my layout:

```
...<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#010D00"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/magic_filter"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:text="Mágico"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/mision_time_filter"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:text="Tiempo"/>

</LinearLayout>...
```

Then I do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.gig_noloc_list_fragment); 

initializeLayout(); // ...(Button) findViewById(R.id.reputation_filter); x4
initializeSpinners();//...magicSpin = new Spinner(this); x4
initializeAdapters();....

magicFil.setOnClickListener(magicListener);
```

and

```
private void initializeAdapters() {
    magicAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.gig_noloc_filter_spinner_view, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.magicItems));
    magicSpin.setAdapter(magicAdap);
    magicSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(magicSListener);
 }
```

and

```
private OnClickListener magicListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        magicSpin.performClick();
    }
};
```

and

```
private OnItemSelectedListener magicSListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        Log.v("HELLO", "BYE");
        magicFil.setText("HOLA");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        magicFil.setText("no tira");
    }

};
```

I don't get any of these messages or texts on the screen or log.

Anybody can tell me what's happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should try putting a Log message to make sure your clicks are being recorded

Comment: onClick is working --->

12-05 17:58:49.425: V/onClick(767): on

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a layout height + width assigned to your elements (spinners, etc)?  If not, you may not have anything to click.